# Query for finding same values of table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
courseTracker(
        student int
        courseID int
)
```

I want to find every student who have the same courses as student 'B'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure of which of these two you want, so I included both.

This will return students who have at least one course in common with B:

```
SELECT DISTINCT student FROM coursetracker
WHERE courseID IN (
    SELECT courseID FROM coursetracker WHERE student = 'B'
)
```

This will return students who have the exact same courses as B:

```
SELECT student FROM (SELECT DISTINCT student FROM coursetracker) c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM coursetracker c1
        FULL JOIN coursetracker c2 ON c1.courseId = c2.courseId
            AND c1.student = c.student AND c2.student = 'B'
    WHERE c1.courseID IS NULL OR c2.courseID IS NULL
)
```

Comment: I tried this and it returns every instance in courseTracker including duplicates

Comment: @MickB, use `DISTINCT` if you don't want duplicates. I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, but it also returns student 'B'

Comment: Yes, well 'B' does have the same courses as himself, per your question. You can add `student <> 'B'` to the `WHERE` clause if you want *other* students with classes in common.